# Wordpress / Woocommerce add comment from code

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

i am trying to write product comments manually from the database.

```
$wpdb->insert($table, 
        array(
                "comment_post_ID"       => '26475',
                "comment_author"        => 'text',
                "comment_author_email"  => "text@text",
                "comment_author_IP"     => "192.168.122.122",
                "comment_date"          => "2017-09-28 14:53:46",
                "comment_date_gmt"      => "2017-09-28 10:53:46",
                "comment_content"       => "Testing Product",
                "comment_karma"         => "0",
                "comment_approved"      => "1",
                "comment_agent"         => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36",
                "comment_parent"        => "0",
                "user_id"               => "0",
));

$ListingID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT comment_ID FROM ". $table ." WHERE comment_post_ID = '26475' AND comment_content = 'Very Good Product'");

        $wpdb->insert($table_comment_meta, 
        array(
                "comment_id" => $ListingID,
                "meta_key"   => "verified",
                "meta_value" => "0",

            ));


        // $wpdb->insert($table_comment_meta, 
        array(
                "comment_id" => $ListingID,
                "meta_key"   => "rating",
                "meta_value" => "5",

            ));
```

After i run the code, and go to the product page, the comment and the rating appears, but the problem that i have, where there reviews are counted before displaying them, it dosen't count this comment.

Someone has any idea what i am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<?php

$time = current_time('mysql');

$data = array(
   'comment_post_ID' => 1,
   'comment_author' => 'admin',
   'comment_author_email' => 'admin@admin.com',
   'comment_author_url' => 'http://',
   'comment_content' => 'content here',
   'comment_type' => '',
   'comment_parent' => 0,
   'user_id' => 1,
   'comment_author_IP' => '127.0.0.1',
   'comment_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042316 Firefox/3.0.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)',
   'comment_date' => $time,
   'comment_approved' => 1,
);

wp_insert_comment($data);

?>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, it works, and i found another way.  Change the table_comment_meta with this  add_comment_meta( $ListingID, 'rating', '5', true);
 wp_update_comment(array("comment_ID" => $ListingID, "comment_approved" => 1));